# php convert same ids in multidimensional array to count from 0

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

well this must a easy one but can't seem to figure it out I have this field `range` in an array that prints an id which repeats it self on array and would like to convert it to a **sequence** count starting from 0.

Live example: https://3v4l.org/Sf4nI#v7.0.33

Current output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [range] => 336
            [year] => 2020
            [month] => 222
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [range] => 336
            [year] => 2020
            [month] => 222
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [range] => 390
            [year] => 2020
            [month] => 222
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [range] => 390
            [year] => 2021
            [month] => 222
        )

)
```

Output I need:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [range] => 0
            [year] => 2020
            [month] => 222
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [range] => 0
            [year] => 2020
            [month] => 222
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [range] => 1
            [year] => 2020
            [month] => 222
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [range] => 1
            [year] => 2021
            [month] => 222
        )

)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the simple solution here is to extract all range values from the array and remove the duplicated values, to make it start from 0 we will use `array_values` and flip it to can get the id by range value

```
$idList = array_flip(array_values(array_unique(array_column($array, 'range'))));
```

now you can get the id for any range you want like this

```
$idList[336];
// or 
$idList[390];
```

https://3v4l.org/kUa8D#v7.0.33

hope it's helpful

Comment: not trying to remove duplicate, just trying to convert range IDs to sequence starting from 0

Comment: @Ered I edit the code to start from 0